Loki implementation on EKS crash loop backoff error
For the implementation of loki & promtail onto EKS cluster,
i have used 2 charts to implement this task,

https://grafana.github.io/loki/charts to add loki . But this repository doesnot exists (404 not found error).
https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts, this chart the loki pod is not running throws error like crash loop back off, when checking the logs it shows like

level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.665665586Z caller=main.go:103 msg="Starting Loki" version="(version=2.6.1, branch=HEAD, revision=6bd05c9a4)"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.665717868Z caller=modules.go:736 msg="RulerStorage is not configured in single binary mode and will not be started."
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.665932002Z caller=server.go:288 http=[::]:3100 grpc=[::]:9095 msg="server listening on addresses"
level=warn ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.666724409Z caller=experimental.go:20 msg="experimental feature in use" feature="In-memory (FIFO) cache - chunksfifocache"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.667405984Z caller=table_manager.go:252 msg="query readiness setup completed" duration=1.859µs distinct_users_len=0
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.667438745Z caller=shipper.go:124 msg="starting index shipper in RW mode"        
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.667566707Z caller=shipper_index_client.go:79 msg="starting boltdb shipper in RW mode"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.667512015Z caller=table_manager.go:134 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.667856732Z caller=table_manager.go:167 msg="handing over indexes to shipper"    
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.670204844Z caller=worker.go:112 msg="Starting querier worker using query-scheduler and scheduler ring for addresses"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.670592752Z caller=modules.go:761 msg="RulerStorage is nil.  Not starting the ruler."
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671785887Z caller=module_service.go:82 msg=initialising module=server
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671855039Z caller=module_service.go:82 msg=initialising module=query-frontend-tripperware
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671858929Z caller=module_service.go:82 msg=initialising module=memberlist-kv    
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.67190554Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=memberlist-kv error="invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671940311Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=usage-report error="failed to start usage-report, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671952101Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=distributor error="failed to start distributor, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671961391Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=store error="failed to start store, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671969531Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=ingester-querier error="failed to start ingester-querier, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671977371Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=ring error="failed to start ring, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671985402Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=query-scheduler error="failed to start query-scheduler, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.671999702Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=compactor error="failed to start compactor, because it depends on module memberlist-kv, which has failed: invalid service state: Failed, expected: Running, failure: invalid service state: Stopping, expected: Running"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.672017222Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=querier error="failed to start querier, because it depends on module ingester-querier, which has failed: context canceled"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.672022262Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=ingester error="failed to start ingester, because it depends on module ring, which has failed: context canceled"
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.672026482Z caller=loki.go:386 msg="module failed" module=query-frontend error="failed to start query-frontend, because it depends on module ring, which has failed: context canceled"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.672048543Z caller=module_service.go:114 msg="module stopped" module=query-frontend-tripperware
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.673281499Z caller=modules.go:1090 msg="server stopped"
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.67330163Z caller=module_service.go:114 msg="module stopped" module=server       
level=info ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.67331413Z caller=loki.go:375 msg="Loki stopped"
failed services
github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run
        /src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:421
main.main
        /src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:105
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
level=error ts=2024-05-11T09:15:00.67335734Z caller=log.go:103 msg="error running loki" err="failed services\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:421\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:105\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581"

Can anyone help me with this, whether it can be helm chart or yaml file to implement prometheus , grafana,loki
I have tried with multiple helm charts and own configuration yaml manifest file, but still dint found any solution on this.
Loki implementation on EKS crash loop backoff error.

Answer question 1, the correct url is https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts.
Answer question 2, memberlist-kv is not available, you need to first check memberlist.

Can you please suggest any link to resolve this memberlist-kv error

You can start investigating your problem from this issue https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/6370. If you need more suggestions, can you share your helm value?

I have installed loki on EKS using the terraform module -> Kubernetes logging by Loki stack (Loki+Promtail). Only the s3 bucket and region has to be provided for the storage configuration.Run terraform apply command, so that the loki and promtail pod will be running.
